# How do I schedule automatic updates on a desktop that's usually turned off?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, automation

OK, this is a complement to another question I posted here on superuser which was for a mac and that got answered today. Here I'll ask the exact same thing but, this time, it will be about a regular desktop PC running Windows 10 Home Edition.

So, I have a desktop PC that's almost always off (neither sleep nor hibernate, it's completely off). What I wish to do is configure it to automatically turn itself on, do any updates (it has the ethernet cable always plugged in so it should always have an internet connection available) and then, once all the updates are done, turn itself back off.

And I wish for all of this to happen without any human interaction. Basically, I want the system to automatically update itself so I won't have to do this manually.

Is it possible to achieve this and, if so, how do I do it?

Comment: You can start with WOL, Wake on LAN.  There's a magic packet that can be sent to a computer to turn it on over the LAN.

Comment: Though I posted the Mac version of this answer, I'm not certain it can be done quite so easily on Windows; as I don't think Win can boot itself from 'cold'. One possibility would be to use a separate mains timer & set the machine to always boot at power-on, though idk if that would work if it was previously properly shut down. I don't know enough about Win to be more helpful, sorry.

Comment: hmm - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN says Win can WOL from cold & Macs can't... which is interesting as Macs can self-boot from cold based on an internal timer...

Comment: Thanks for the info. Apparently it is indeed possible to use Wake on Lan on my BIOS thankfully. So all I have to do is use my router to send this packet to my PC. The issue now is how to automate the desktop to start doing updates without me logging in. Still looking into that. Thanks for the advice!